# list to populate the relationship record

Tags: apex

I have junction object CT__c , Which has Mlookup1__c , Mlookup2__c
case is related with CT object

i am populating the case on load

```
case c= [select id,CT__c,CT__c,CT__r.Mlookup1__c,CT__r.Mlookup2__c  ];
```

Initally CT__c = null

Now i want to assign the relationship value to show in UI, So i am doing like this

```
c.CI__c = updateCaseobj.CI__c ;
c.CI__r.Mlookup1__c = updateCaseobj.CI__r.Mlookup1__c;
```

But its showing attempt to null refernce. Is there a way to fix this

Comment: when u give -1 u should give the reason. so it would be helpful to update myself .

Comment: Maybe that was because it seems like this is the type of question that's probably been asked before. Might be that appropriate "research effort" here may have been to debug `c.CI__r` prior to asking the question. Also, including the error message verbatim, and providing a clear indication of which line the error is for is never a bad idea. Not sure why it was downvoted, but I'll upvote to offset that.

Answer (score 3):

Reference fields have a kind of double life. When you refer to and assign the `__c` version of the field, you're interacting with an Id field only. It has no attributes; it's just an Id.

When you refer to the `__r` version of the field, you're indexing into the child sObject to access its fields.

When you query an object using field names like `Reference__r.Name`, you also get access to the `Reference__c` field, which has the child object's Id. However, this *doesn't* go the other direction. When you assign or query the `__c` version of the lookup field, you *don't* get access to the sObject version of the child, and you cannot access its fields.

You would need to query here to get access to the field `Mlookup__c`. You're receiving a `NullPointerException` because the sObject "side" of the relationship field is not populated, just the Id value.